# Cant find my phonegap app in the android file system after installing the apk file

Tags: android, cordova

Im currently in the process of byuilding an app with phonegap on android.

I Prepared a "spoof app " with tests of some functionnalities i wanted to try before starting to develop fully.

I built my app and signed it so i may install it on my phone with the apk.

The problem is , my app works fine but i cant find the file system of the app in any of the devices i tested the app on. I wanted to retrieve the SQLite database or a file i created but i cant because i cant find the filesystem of the app in the device.

Is there anyway other than rooting the device to see my app in the phone filesystem when plugged with usb?

Or is there any way i can retrieve easily the databases my app created on the phone?

EDIT: my devices dont have SDCARDS and doesnt support SDCARDS either.

Comment: You might add a comment here with the version of Android you're working against. I'm not certain that will help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: android 3.2 is the version of the tablet

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED

Since i found out that i would have to root the phone or the tablet to acess the filesystem i review my app functionnalities and i found out i could create a foler on the phone with phonegap , but still i couldnt see it. 
I then opened the DDMS perspective in eclipse and looked throught the filesystem and found out that the folders i saw in my phone were in the mnt folder, in the sdcard directory. (mnt/sdcard)

I then used the filesystem acess of phonegap to create a directory on my phone.

```
  fileSystem.root.getDirectory("**/mnt/sdcard/com.seventest.com**",{create:true, exclusive: false},gotDir,fails);
```

So now i can access a directory and push anything in it i need to access for my app to work with.